# How do I get an array of substrings from an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of string like:

```
var myArray=['rwt-cable1','rwt-cable42','rwt-cable40',...]
```

But what I am really interested in is:

`['cable1','cable42','cable40',...]`

What would be the best way? I'm currently looping through items and extract substrings to get my output array.

Comment: I'd do a `myArray.map(..)`, but yes, ultimately you need to loop and substring/regex-replace or something along those lines.

Comment: `['rwt-cable1', 'rwt-cable42', 'rwt-cable40'].forEach(function(elem, index) {
  ip[index] = elem.replace('rwt-', '');
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a regular expression:

```
var myArray= ['rwt-cable1','rwt-cable42','rwt-cable40'];
myArray = myArray.map(v => v.replace(/^rwt\-/,""));
console.log(myArray); //["cable1", "cable42", "cable40"]
```

The regex `^rwt\-` will match the text `rxt-` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: You've got my vote for explicitly only targeting the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `split` and `map` function

```js
var res = ['rwt-cable1', 'rwt-cable42', 'rwt-cable40'].map(e => e.split('-')[1]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I've removed the off-topic comments on this post. If you spot bad practices in code, feel free to edit those out as long as the meaning of the answer doesn't change. Changing the means of output while not touching the actual logic that makes the answer is fine.

Comment: that was pretty funny(those comments about `document.write`) ... the discussion could be endless ))

Comment: @MadaraUchiha `document.body.textContent = res;` seems to not work in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach would be

```
['rwt-cable1', 'rwt-cable42', 'rwt-cable40'].map(x => x.replace('rwt-', ''))
// ["cable1", "cable42", "cable40"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative using `Array.map` and `Array.slice` functions:

```
var myArray = ['rwt-cable1','rwt-cable42','rwt-cable40'],
    result = myArray.map(function(v){ return v.slice(4); });

console.log(result);   // ["cable1", "cable42", "cable40"]
```